# usermod says account doesn't exist but adduser says it does

Tags: adduser, accounts

I run the command

```
usermod -a -G dialout amashreghi
```

but I get amashreghi doesn't exists, however, when I try to add the user using adduser

```
adduser amashreghi
```

It says that amashreghi already exists. What's going on?!

Comment: Does `amashreghi` have a password?

Comment: Yes, I am sudo user but not root. I have tried usermod with sudo as well though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To edit `/etc/group` directly use **vigr**

From `man vigr`

```
NAME
       vipw, vigr - edit the password, group, shadow-password or shadow-group file

SYNOPSIS
       vipw [options]

       vigr [options]

DESCRIPTION
       The vipw and vigr commands edits the files /etc/passwd and /etc/group, respectively. With the -s flag,
       they will edit the shadow versions of those files, /etc/shadow and /etc/gshadow, respectively. The
       programs will set the appropriate locks to prevent file corruption. When looking for an editor, the
       programs will first try the environment variable $VISUAL, then the environment variable $EDITOR, and
       finally the default editor, vi(1).
```

Hence, you can edit the `/etc/group` file with

```
sudo vigr
```

The format of group entries can be found in man.
From `man group`:

```
NAME
       group - user group file

DESCRIPTION
       The  /etc/group file is a text file that defines the groups on the system.  There is one entry per line,
       with the following format:

           group_name:password:GID:user_list

       The fields are as follows:

       group_name  the name of the group.

       password    the (encrypted) group password.  If this field is empty, no password is needed.

       GID         the numeric group ID.

       user_list   a list of the usernames that are members of this group, separated by commas.

FILES
       /etc/group
```

Comment: Might want to do `sudo grpconv` if you are doing this with `newgrp`!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. (I'm assuming that you're ready to delete everything associated with this user and start over, don't run these if you're not.)

```
userdel -r amashreghi
grep amashreghi /etc/passwd
```

If that second command returns anything, run:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/passwd
```

Remove the line that begins with `amashreghi`, and save the file. Try adding the user again now.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout amashreghi
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do this:

```
sudo vim /etc/group
```

and add your name to the desired group, like:

```
somegroup:x:25:yourusername
```

Comment: Vim is not recommended to edit the group file: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79177/262708